# Laptop woke up from sleep. Now lost keyboard and mouse

Tags: battery, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 21.04 installed. The laptop was on battery power. It went to sleep. When I open the lid it wakes up but **can't use keyboard** (tried in-built/external keyboard) **or mouse. Unable to force reboot.**

I opened the base cover in an attempt to disconnect the battery but the connector (red arrow in pic) is so small and flimsy and do not want to risk breaking it. Its a brand new Dell 7610 laptop.

What options do I have to get the laptop rebooted?
[Battery connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCpU0.png)

Comment: Press power button for 5-8 secs it will be force shutdown

Comment: Pls read my post again. No keyboard or mouse.

Comment: You are on laptop, laptop has a power button from which you switch on pc

Comment: Power button is integrated into my keyboard.